# Query speed reverse OneToOneField

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm in doubt between 2 ways of modelling my allocations of Articles to Magazines. Some pseudo code for the models could be:

```
class Article():
  title = ...
  text = ...
  magazine = ForeignKey(Magazine, db_index=True)


class Magazine():
   ...

class ArticleMagazineAllocation():
  article = OneToOneField(Article, db_index=True)
  magazine = ForeignKey(Magazine, db_index=True)
  allocated_on = DateTimeField()
```

I could create a ForeignKey to Magazine from Article. Alternatively I could use the ArticleMagazineAllocation model to connect both, which I would prefer for a number of reasons, to store extra data about the "allocation".

For the first case, the query would be:
magazine_articles = Article.objects.filter(magazine = mymagazine)

For the second, the query would be:
magazine_aticles = Article.objects.filter(articlemagazineallocation__magazine = mymagazine)

With a LOT (millions) of Articles and a few (hundreds) Magazines, would there be a considerable speed penalty in using the second method?

Comment: I will answer myself after doing some tests: the second method was way too slow, probably due to the outer join.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to model a many to many relationship that requires additional data on the relationship itself, you should create a intermediate model. In order to query related models directly you could place a `ManyToMany` field on either model, using the option `through`. To query related models, you can always use the double underscore query syntax in Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

As for performance, you can use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` quen querying large datasets that span to multiple tables.

Comment: I know about the use of select_related and prefetch_related, thanks for reminding, but the question was about the difference in performance between the 2 query types in my original post. I know it might be database related, but just a general idea.

Comment: If you are using an intermediate model, you will always need to make a three tables join. If you want to denormalize by adding a direct link, you would be using a two tables join. It's up to you to determine what you want. As for me, I don't think it would be such a penalty, but then again, you need to test.